# How to select multiple images from the page and drop them into external apps or a local folder to be downloaded directly using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application that has a Razor page to display a set of images and I want to select several images, then drag and drop them into a local folder to download them directly or drop them into external applications, the idea is as if we are working on Windows Explorer, please excuse me I'm new and I'm still at the beginning of the journey, any information will be appreciated and grateful, thanks in advance for the help.

```
@foreach (var image in Model.images)
{
   <img src="~/Web/assets/img/carImages/@image.ImageUrl" class="img-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-6">
}
```

I asked my question to Chat.openai.com and it was as follows:

My Question:
I have a web page with many images and I have written JavaScript code when clicking on any image that is added to the "selected" class. I want when the user drags and drops an image containing a "selected" class to a local folder on the user's device copies of all images containing the same class are created to that folder where the user dropped them Give me the exact detail codes to achieve this?

```
        <div class="row portfolio-container" id="image-container">
            @foreach (var img in Model.imgs!)
            {
                <img draggable="true" src="~/Web/assets/img/carImages/@img.ImageUrl" id="@img.ImageUrl" alt="@img.ImageUrl" class="img img-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            }
        </div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>

    // Step 1: Add click event listener to images
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

    // add onclick event listener to toggle image selection status
    images.forEach(function (image) {
        image.onclick = function () {
            if (image.classList.contains('selected')) {
                image.classList.remove('selected');
                selectedImages.splice(selectedImages.indexOf(image), 1);
            } else {
                image.classList.add('selected');
                selectedImages.push(image);
            }
        };
    });

</script>
}
```

Thus my question was answered:

To implement drag and drop functionality and create copies of selected images in a local folder on the user's device, you can use the following

```
    @model List<ImageModel>

<div class="row portfolio-container" id="image-container">
    @foreach (var img in Model)
    {
        <img draggable="true" src="~/Web/assets/img/carImages/@img.ImageUrl" id="@img.ImageUrl" alt="@img.ImageUrl" class="img img-fluid col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    }
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        // Step 1: Add click and drag event listeners to images
        let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

    // Add onclick event listener to toggle image selection status
    images.forEach(function (image) {
        image.onclick = function () {
            if (image.classList.contains('selected')) {
                image.classList.remove('selected');
                selectedImages.splice(selectedImages.indexOf(image), 1);
            } else {
                image.classList.add('selected');
                selectedImages.push(image);
            }
        };
    });

    // Add ondragstart event listener to store image source in dataTransfer object
    images.forEach(function (image) {
        image.ondragstart = function (event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', image.src);
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        };
    });

    // Add ondrop event listener to create copies of selected images in local folder
    document.body.ondrop = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        let folderName = 'selected_images';
        let folderPath = '';

        if (files.length > 0) {
            let file = files[0];
            let parentPath = file.path.substring(0, file.path.lastIndexOf('\\'));

            folderPath = parentPath + '\\' + folderName;

            // Check if selected_images folder exists, if not create it
            if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(folderPath);
            }
        }

        // Create copies of selected images in selected_images folder
        selectedImages.forEach(function (image) {
            let sourcePath = image.src.replace(window.location.origin, '');
            let destPath = folderPath + '\\' + sourcePath.substring(sourcePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            // Use AJAX call to create copy of image in selected_images folder
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CopyImage", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { sourcePath: sourcePath, destPath: destPath },
                success: function () {
                    console.log('Image copied successfully.');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('Error occurred while copying image.');
                    console.log('Error message: ' + error);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    // Add ondragover event listener to allow dropping of files
    document.body.ondragover = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    };
</script>
```

}

In this code, we use an AJAX call to copy the selected images to the local folder instead of using '

We've also added a:

```
public IActionResult CopyImage(string sourcePath, string destPath)
{
    try
    {
        // Get absolute path of source and destination files
        string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, sourcePath);
        string destFilePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, destPath);

        // Copy file to destination folder
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destFilePath);

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this code does not work and I have attached it to probably help get an idea to answer my question.  All thanks and appreciation to everyone who contributes to solving this question.

Comment: I'm suffering from this problem, and the answer to the question will benefit everyone.